# Does the simplified flat rate for meals already reflect the 50% deduction?

Tags: taxes, canada

In Canadian taxes for the self employed, they offer a simplified method for meal deductions with a flat rate per meal and/or a max per day.  Do the amounts mentioned already factor in the 50% you're actually allowed to deduct?  Ie. if the flat rate is $23 per meal, do you deduct 23 or is the allowable deduction 11.50?  I can't find this specified anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

This link makes it pretty clear for individuals: https://www.canada.ca/en/revenue-agency/services/tax/individuals/topics/about-your-tax-return/tax-return/completing-a-tax-return/deductions-credits-expenses/line-229-other-employment-expenses/transportation-employees/meals-lodging-including-showers.html that you can deduct 50% of the flat rate of $23, ie $11.50.

This link which I think applies to your situation https://www.canada.ca/en/revenue-agency/services/tax/businesses/topics/sole-proprietorships-partnerships/business-expenses.html#mealsandentertainmentallowablepartonly is slightly less clear but implies the same thing.

Comment: Thanks Vicky.  The top link is specifically for "transportation employees" which is probably why I never found myself on that page, but it's definitely helpful to finally see it written out in such a way, as it's safe to assume they mean the same for all professions in this case.  The second link I had been to and I still dont see it imply anything either way.  We are touring musicians and you'd think there would be more guidance out there for this kid of thing.  Thanks again for that link.